# Draw graph of XOR problem (Neural Network)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams

Here are the 2 images I need to draw:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/xor-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need? Since I didn't have any data, I did mostly by comparing it to your images.

[image: tikz images]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{   cirwhite/.style={draw=gray,circle,fill=white,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=2pt,line width=0.2mm},
            cirred/.style={draw=gray,circle,fill=red,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=2pt,line width=0.2mm},
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm,y=2mm]

       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (-1,0) -- (15,0); %draw axis
       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (0,-1) -- (0,15);

       \node[anchor=west] at (15,0) {$x_1$};  % draw axis labels
       \node[anchor=south] at (0,15) {$x_2$};

       \draw (-3,7) -- (7,-3);    % draw diagonal lines
       \draw (-3,14) -- (14,-3); 
       \draw[gray] (0,8) -- (8,8);   % lines
       \draw[gray] (8,0) -- (8,8);

       \node[cirwhite] at (0,0) {}; % circles
       \node[cirred] at (0,8) {}; 
       \node[cirred] at (8,0) {};    
       \node[cirwhite] at (8,8) {};                                      

    \end{tikzpicture} \hspace{2cm} \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm,y=2mm] % HERE STARTS THE SECOND GRAPH
       %draw horizontal line   
       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (-1,0) -- (15,0);
       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (0,-1) -- (0,15);

       %draw years
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \data using int(0+\x)] in {0,1,...,14}{ 
            \draw (\x,0) node[below=5pt,anchor=north,font=\scriptsize] {}; 
            \draw (\x,0) node[above=1pt,anchor=north,font=\scriptsize] {};      
       }    

       \node[anchor=west] at (15,0) {$\phi_1$};
       \node[anchor=south] at (0,15) {$\phi_2$};

       \draw (-3,9) -- (9,-3);
       \draw[gray] (0,8) -- (8,8);    
       \draw[gray] (8,0) -- (8,8);

       \node[cirwhite,label={[blue, anchor=south east]above:4}] at (1.5,8) {}; 
       \node[cirwhite,label={[blue, anchor=south west]right:1}] at (8,1.5) {};  

       \node[cirred,label={[blue, anchor=south west]above left:2}] at (2.3,2.3) {}; 
       \node[cirred,label={[blue, anchor=south west]below right:3}] at (2.3,2.3) {};                                    

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Coordinates of points were: 
for 1st figure- (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)
for 2nd figure- (1.0000, 0.1353), (0.3678, 0.3678), (0.3678, 0.3678), (0.1353, 1.0000)

Comment: @pushpen.paul Do you want me to update the answer with your measurements? The graphs slightly changed, of course, but they look more or less the same. :)

Comment: No, you've already done a great job and I myself did necessary changes. :-)

Comment: OK, one more thing... In a similar figure, I need to draw the separator line to be dashed. Is there any available shortcut for that?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Ok then. :) And sure! You can type `\draw[dashed]`. You can also type `loosely dashed` there for the dashes to be more spaced.